# How to create system wide retry policy in MassTransit and modify/overwrite it in specific consumer?

Tags: masstransit

I would like to create system wide retry policy (retry x times every y seconds) but modify/overwrite it in specific consumer (some exception should be ignored and moved to error queue without retry)

I was thinking that something like this should work(bus configuration part):

```
 services.AddMassTransit<T>(
                massTransit =>
                {
                    massTransit.UsingRabbitMq(
                        (context, cfg) =>
                        {
                            cfg.UseMessageRetry(r =>
                            {
                                r.Intervals(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
                            });
                    ....
                     massTransit.AddConsumers(assembly);
```

consumer definition part:

```
public class DoSomethingConsumerDefinition :
    ConsumerDefinition<DoSomethingConsumer>
    {
        protected override void ConfigureConsumer(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator,
            IConsumerConfigurator<DoSomethingConsumer> consumerConfigurator)
        {
            endpointConfigurator.UseMessageRetry(r => 
            { 
                r.Ignore<DoSomethingSpecificException>();
                r.Intervals(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            });            
        }
    }
```

I can't achieve it this way. DoSomethingSpecificException is retried using global policy.
What is the correct way to achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When configuring multiple retry policies, which is what happens in this case, you'd need to ensure that exceptions you do not want retried are properly overridden. If you ignore the exception, it isn't handled by the retry filter, so you'd need to handle it with no retry:

```cs
public class DoSomethingConsumerDefinition :
    ConsumerDefinition<DoSomethingConsumer>
{
    protected override void ConfigureConsumer(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator,
        IConsumerConfigurator<DoSomethingConsumer> consumerConfigurator)
    {
        endpointConfigurator.UseMessageRetry(r =>
        {
            r.Handle<DoSomethingSpecificException>();
            r.None();
        });
        endpointConfigurator.UseMessageRetry(r => 
        { 
            r.Ignore<DoSomethingSpecificException>();
            r.Intervals(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        });            
    }
}
```

With the `None` retry filter, it would signify that exception should not be retried by a retry/redelivery filter defined prior to the *None* filter.